# How to store list items within an array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to store all list items of several list of the same class within an array.

for exemple:

```
<ul class="myList">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="myList">
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Script file:

```
var arr_list_items = [];

$('ul.myList').each(function(){
  while( !$(this).empty() ) {
    list_item = $(this).find('li:first');
    arr_list_items.push( list_item );
    list_item.remove();
  }
});
```

The list items are removed, but the array returns empty. Why?

Comment: you can add code `console.info(1111)`; inside you `while`,you will find it does not console

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var array = [];
$('.myList li').each(function(i, li) {
  array.push($(li));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for any complex logic.

You can use the [`.get()` method](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to retrieve an array of the elements matched by the jQuery object:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ee8gh6dq/)

```
var arr_list_items = $('.myList li').remove().get();

console.log(arr_list_items);
// [li, li, li, li, li]
```

Alternatively, you could also use the [`.map()` method](https://api.jquery.com/map/):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3xn4em3n/)

```
var arr_list_items = $('.myList li').remove().map(function () {
    return this;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr_list_items = [];

$('ul.myList').each(function (i,n) {
    $(n).find('li').each(function (j, m) {
        arr_list_items.push(m);
    }).remove();
});

for (var i = 0; i < arr_list_items.length; i++) {
    console.info(arr_list_items[i]);
}
```

Because I am poor in English, so I can not explain the code,but I think you can understand it

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr_list_items = [];

$('ul.myList').each(function(){
  $(this).find('li').each(function(){
    arr_list_items.push(this);
    $(this).remove();
  });
});

console.info(arr_list_items);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myList">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="myList">
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```