# Using Puppeteer and jQuery to scrape all unordered list items to an array

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I'm using puppeteer with jQuery and NodeJS to try and get list items from a web page:

```html
        <table>
            <td class="hr">
                <ul class="people">
                    <li class = "person">Richard</li>
                    <li class = "person">Linus</li>
                    <li class = "person">Brian</li>
                    <li class = "team_lead">Charles</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td class="manufacturing">
                <ul class="people">
                    <li class = "person">Alan</ul>
                    <li class = "person">Margret</li>
                    <li class = "person">Ken</li>
                    <li class = "person">Edsger</li>
                    <li class = "team_lead">Dennis</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td class="design">
                <ul class="people">
                    <li class = "person">Bill</li>
                    <li class = "person">Ada</li>
                    <li class = "person">Steve</li>
                    <li class = "person">Ken</li>
                    <li class = "team_lead">Dennis</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </table>
```

and using the nodeJS code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

async function main(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless : false, defaultViewport: {width: 1920, height: 1080}});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("${url}");
    const htmlContent = await page.content();
    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlContent);

    let peopleList = [];

    $(`table td .people`).each(function(i, li){
        peopleList.push(li.text());
    });
    console.log(`people: ${peopleList}`);
}
main();
```

I have got this code for parsing through the list from another stackoverflow answer:
[How to store list items within an array with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330892/how-to-store-list-items-within-an-array-with-jquery) and using a Udemy tutorial, and tried to edit it accordingly.

I am looking to store each name in a two dimensional array, so something like:

```
peopleList = [[Richard, Linus, Brian, Charles], [Alan, Margret, Edsger, Dennis], [Bill, Ada, Steve, Ken, Dennis]];
```

however I am getting a single string:

```
RichardLinusBrianCharlesAlanMargretEdsgerDenisBillAdSteveKenDennis,RichardLinusBrianCharlesAlanMargretEdsgerDenisBillAdSteveKenDennis,...
```

(repeat for each ul element) and when I try to go deeper and include li tags I just get an empty string.

1. Is there any way I can save in the desired way?
2. I am using an private site and therefore have removed the url and changed people to Computer scientists. Is there any way to point Puppeteer to a site run locally, eg: localhost/index.html?

Comment: You can use something like `JSDom` - just retrieve the page with a http request, parse the DOM with nodeJS and then use things like `querySelector` so you don't even need to use jQuery (because its 2023). That seems easier than spinning up Chrome if you don't need it for something like screenshotting.

Answer (score 2):

There is [no need to use Cheerio with Puppeteer](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#using-a-separate-html-parser-with-puppeteer). Puppeteer already works with the live page, so it generally doesn't make sense to snapshot the page into a string, then dump it into a separate library. This is inefficient and leads to confusing bugs when the snapshot goes stale.

Instead, use `page.$$eval(yourSelector, browserCallback)` to do the job:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.6.0

const html = `<HTML pasted from your question>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const sel = "table td .people .person";
  await page.waitForSelector(sel);
  const people = await page.$$eval(
    sel,
    els => els.map(el => el.textContent.trim())
  );
  console.log(people);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Output:

```js
[
  'Richard', 'Linus',
  'Brian',   'Alan',
  'Bill',    'Ada',
  'Steve',   'Ken'
]
```

The joined string issue was resolved above by using the selector `table td .people .person`, which would technically work in the Cheerio approach as well.

If you want to keep the categories distinct, you could use a nested query:

```js
// ...
const people = await page.$$eval("table td", els =>
  els.map(el => ({
    category: el.className,
    people: [...el.querySelectorAll(".person")].map(e =>
      e.textContent.trim()
    ),
  }))
);
// ...
```

which gives:

```js
[
  { category: 'hr', people: [ 'Richard', 'Linus', 'Brian' ] },
  {
    category: 'manufacturing',
    people: [ 'Alan', 'Margret', 'Ken', 'Edsger' ]
  },
  { category: 'design', people: [ 'Bill', 'Ada', 'Steve', 'Ken' ] }
]
```

All that said, if the page you're working with has the data you want statically, using `fetch` and Cheerio may make sense. But I'm assuming you're working with a SPA or website that requires some interaction to get to the scrape point, or there's some other good motivator for using Puppeteer.

As another aside, if you wind up sticking with Puppeteer but prefer to use jQuery, you can either [add it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987516/inject-jquery-into-puppeteer-page), or use it if the page happens to have jQuery included already. You'll then access `$` inside an `evaluate`-family callback that runs in the browser context. This makes more sense than using Cheerio in most cases, since you're taking advantage of the realtime page abilities of Puppeteer and won't suffer from stale data issues.

To answer your other question, for demo and reproducibility purposes, I use `setContent` as shown above, but you can [run a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497334/how-to-run-html-file-on-localhost) and navigate to your page on localhost. Just make sure to include the port.

Comment: The data is sort of static, would be edited when people leave or are recruited, but that is few and far between. Yes, it's an internal part of a public website that needs to be logged into. I found out how to login using puppeteer hence continuing to use it, but the tutorials I've used tack cheerio on and I'm fairly new at this and am just figuring it out. I will try as you suggested and use jquery and a local server.

Comment: "Static" just refers to whether it's part of the original HTML response or whether it's added later dynamically with JS. If the former, then you probably don't need Puppeteer. If you need to login, then you may need to make the request with a cookie or something. Puppeteer is probably easier at that point. I don't really recommend using jQuery with Puppeteer, but it's _possible_ and handy in certain situations where you need Sizzle or have pre-written, complex jQuery code. Just using plain Puppeteer and vanilla browser JS is my preferred approach otherwise. But yeah, skip Cheerio for sure.